# Can't make WKWebView send cookies

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView with cookies in its Cookie storage.

If I debug what is in the cookie storage, I see the `JSESSIONID` cookie I'm interested in:

```
[NSHTTPCookie]
name            = JSESSIONID
value           = 36A3E5D5C4382D5220E70C3D29A4F5E9
domain          = my.domain.net
path            = /
expiresDate     = (null)
sessionOnly     = 1
secure          = 0
comment         = (null)
commentURL      = (null)
version         = 1
```

However, when I load an URL with the webview like this:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:request]; // request URL is @"https://my.domain.net/47874/1105451/index.html"
```

The cookie is not sent !!!

The only way I've found to send it is to add it manually to the request like this:

```
[request addValue:@"JSESSIONID=36A3E5D5C4382D5220E70C3D29A4F5E9" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

Which should not be necessary in my opinion...

But that doesn't solve my problem anyway as the `index.html` I load has two `.js` files dependencies on the same domain (`my.domain.net`) that require the `JSESSIONID` cookie to be successfully fetch and again, the WKWebView does NOT send my `JSESSIONID` cookie.

This issue is really driving me mad after days of tests / tries to make this simple thing work...

By the way: before any moderator does so, I have already checked all cookie related issue with WKWebView reported on SO or other sites (github, etc...) so please do not close this question before asking me if it is indeed a duplicate or not. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this?